# Unix shell function for adding directories to PATH

Tags: bash, portability, unix, zsh, ksh

Adding a directory to the `PATH` in Unix/Linux is a very common task.  However, what if the directory is already in the path?  My goal is to write a shell function (preferably portable) that will add a directory to the front or back of the `PATH` variable, but only if it's not already there.

Here's what I have (syntax is in `zsh` / `bash`):

```
#-------
# DESC: Adds a directory to the PATH if it's not already in the PATH
# ARGS:
#  1 - The directory to add
#  2 - Which end of PATH to add to.  Use "front" to prepend.
#-------
add2path() {
  if ! echo $PATH | egrep "(^|:)$1(:|\$)" > /dev/null ; then
    if [[ $2 = "front" ]]; then
      PATH="$1:$PATH"
    else
      PATH="$PATH:$1"
    fi
    export PATH
  fi
}
```

This function works.  I have tested it on Ubuntu, Solaris, and FreeBSD.  And I have tested it in `bash`, `zsh`, and `ksh`.  But I want to make sure that it is as portable (first and foremost), readable, and as efficient as possible.

### Remarks

- I know that the `=~` operator would be more readable, but I had trouble with it not working on certain OSes, particularly Solaris.
- I know I could (and arguably should) use `grep -Fq` instead of `egrep` routing to `/dev/null`, but again this didn't work on certain OSes (Solaris)

  - Ironically, the way to fix this on Solaris is to add `/usr/xpg4/bin` to the PATH.  :)

Comment: If you want to write a portable shell function, instead of targeting certain shell interpreters and OSes, you should just write it with pure POSIX syntax and make sure it is executed in a POSIX context (which is the trickiest part).

Answer (score 10):

`grep` is most likely an overkill. After setting `IFS=":"`, the `$PATH` is conveniently split into words. Then the presence of the directory can be determined in a simple loop

```
    IFS=":"
    for pathdir in $PATH; do
        if [ $pathdir == $1]; then return; fi
    done

    # Now restore IFS and modify path as needed.
```

Comment: Won't this be slower, though?  In this solution, we're using a script to perform looping whereas the original solution has `grep`, which runs at the *machine level*, doing the looping for us.

Comment: @Sildoreth No. Looping via builtins is fast (at least comparing to a `fork/exec` of `grep` invocation).

Comment: I like this. But I'd go with the shorter `$pathdir == $1 && return`

Comment: You probably don't want to just `return` there without also restoring `IFS`.

Comment: Here is a [nice way to restore IFS](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/264947/101839)

Answer (score 5):

Here is one way to make it more portable and robust:

```
add2path() {
  if ! echo "$PATH" | PATH=$(getconf PATH) grep -Eq '(^|:)'"${1:?missing argument}"'(:|\$)' ; then # Use the POSIX grep implementation
    if [ -d "$1" ]; then # Don't add a non existing directory to the PATH
      if [ "$2" = front ]; then # Use a standard shell test
        PATH="$1:$PATH"
      else
        PATH="$PATH:$1"
      fi
      export PATH
    fi
  fi
}
```

I have added a test to quit the function with an error should no argument be passed.

`PATH=$(getconf PATH)` is the portable way to have the POSIX commands first in the PATH. This is solving the issue you had with Solaris where, not to break existing Solaris scripts portability, the first `grep` command found in the PATH is not POSIX compliant.

Using `[[` is not specified by POSIX so it is better to stick with `[` to do tests.

`$2` should then be quoted to avoid clashes with `[` operands.

`front`, being a constant string, need not be quoted.

Excluding non directories to be added looks to me a reasonable approach but is of course an optional extension which you might remove.

Comment: It's not necessarily bad to add a non-existent directory to the PATH.  For instance, say I always want to be able to run from `~/bin`, and I have the exact same rc files on many machines (which is the case for me).  There might be cases where the `~/bin` directory doesn't exist *yet*.  Then if I add it on one machine, I'd have to re-run my rc file to place that directory in the PATH.

Comment: @Sildoreth Indeed, I have added comments about it in my reply.

Comment: @TobySpeight Not just a matter of style. Quotes are definitely required here to allow adding a path with an embedded space, or not to fail when passed an empty argument.

Comment: @TobySpeight Okay, I misunderstood your comment. I just meant that the quotes were superfluous around `front` but were required around `$2`. You might indeed keep them around the former without breaking the script.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant.  But it looked like you were saying that it shouldn't be quoted.  I think that's actually just a typo, and I've made an edit accordingly.  (Sometimes in English, a single letter makes all the difference - e.g. *"a few people"* is very much more than *"few people"*!)

Comment: @TobySpeight Thanks for the edit and for teaching me how to use modal verbs! :-)

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you need to export `PATH`.
By the time this script of yours is sourced,
`PATH` should be exported already by startup scripts of the OS.
See also [this post on Unix SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/26047/83381).

If you don't mind dropping `ksh` support,
then you can replace `echo` with a *here-string*:

```
egrep "(^|:)$1(:|\$)" <<< "$PATH" > /dev/null
```

Answer (score 3):

[vnp's](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/88251/85720) solution is pretty good because it uses only builtin. Here's another way, which doesn't modify the `IFS`:

```
add2path() {
  case :$PATH: in
    *:$1:*) ;;
    *)
      if [ "$2" = 'front' ]; then
        PATH="$1:$PATH"
      else
        PATH="$PATH:$1"
      fi
      export PATH
      ;;
  esac
}
```

Comment: **This is terrible.** There is *no* way to uniquely match pathnames in `:`-delimited strings in raw bash without either manually iterating the `${IFS}` or matching via the regex-based `=~` operator. Without profiling, it's unclear which is more performant. What is clear, however, is that this answer fails in fairly obviously common edge cases (e.g., when the passed dirname is itself a substring of an existing dirname on the current `${PATH}`). Notably, `PATH=/usr/bin && add2path /bin/ front && echo $PATH` prints `/usr/bin` rather than the expected `/bin:/usr/bin`. (*Woops.*)

Comment: @CecilCurry Thanks for spotting the bug. I've fixed it and now the function works just fine.

Comment: Simpler method: `case ":$PATH:" in *:$1:*)` - if we add `:` onto each end, we no longer have to special-case the first and last members.  I'm not 100% sure, but I think `$1` might need quotes there, too.  (Oh, and we can use `[` instead of `[[`, to regain portability).

Comment: @TobySpeight Good idea. It does in fact simplifies this example a little bit.

Answer (score -1):

I liked the idea presented by @vpn but it's only a snippet so I coded a working function using just bash builtins and separating the functionality into two different calls (append/prepend) which IMHO makes it more robust.

[@vpns's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/88251/184572) doesn't include the whole function and also has the IFS problem. This working code doesn't use grep and IFS is untouched.

```bsh
not_in_path(){
    IFS=":" read -r -a path_array <<< "$PATH"
    for pathdir in ${path_array[@]}; do
        if [ "$pathdir" == "$1" ]; then
            return 1
        fi
    done
    return 0
}
append2path(){
    not_in_path "$1" && export PATH="$PATH:$1"
}
prepend2path(){
    not_in_path "$1" && export PATH="$1:$PATH"
}
```

Usage is pretty simple, just:

- `append2path /my/path` to append
- `prepend2path /my/path` to prepend

From what I understand I can rely on PATH being already present so it is not necessary to handle the case of PATH being empty or not set and colon should be omitted.

Also there's no need to `export` the variable. It doesn't harm, though and for me it is clearer what the function intends to achieve. Maybe there are other issues. Happy to see some feedback.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/150447)

Comment: You have presented an alternative solution, but haven't reviewed the code. Please [edit] to show what aspects of the question code prompted you to write this version, and in what ways it's an improvement over the original.  It may be worth (re-)reading [answer].

Comment: @TobySpeight did you find any specific issues in the code which made you suggest that the code is not reviewed? I added a reasoning. It is more a continuation of an idea than an alternative solution.

Comment: @rolfl What makes you think I had a question? I wrote the code to the best of my knowledge but perhaps someone sees something that I don't. Thus the last two sentences. That's all

Comment: Where is the review of the code in the question?  All I see is a different set of functions that achieve something similar.  Can you point to a sentence where you make an observation on the code that was presented for review?

Comment: @TobySpeight  Sorry, should I link the answer in question. Didn't know how to do that. The sentence would be:  "@vpns's answer doesn't include the whole function and also has the IFS problem. This working code doesn't use grep and IFS is untouched."

Comment: So it looks like this isn't a review, but is something of an extended comment on a [different answer](/a/88251/75307)?

Comment: It looks like you have some pretty good suggestions in there - separate functions to append and prepend is certainly more user-friendly and robust than relying on a second argument to switch behaviours, for example.  That's something that could be a worthwhile review and good intro to your alternative solution!