# Pathmunge function in zsh

Tags: performance, zsh

`pathmunge` is an often-seen function in shell initialization files, used to add entries to the `PATH` environment variable without duplication. Examples:

1. [Fedora `/etc/profile`'s `pathmunge`](https://git.fedorahosted.org/cgit/setup.git/tree/profile#n11).
2. [How can I cleanly add to $PATH? - Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/124444/70524)
3. [Unix shell function for adding directories to PATH](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/88236/67162)

I wrote this `pathmunge` variation in zsh:

```sh
pathmunge() {
    local path_array before
    # The default is to prepend the argument to PATH
    before=1
    case $1 in
        after)
            # Append to PATH
            before=
            ;&
        before)
            shift
            ;;
    esac
    # Split PATH on : into an array
    path_array=(${(As.:.)PATH})
    # Then remove the arguments from it, since they are to be added in the
    # order specified
    path_array=(${path_array:|argv})
    if [[ -n $before ]]
    then
        # Reverse the order of the arguments, so that:
        #    for f in ...; pathmunge f
        # and
        #    pathmunge ...
        # have the same effect.
        path_array=(${(Oa)argv} $path_array)
    else
        path_array=($path_array $argv)
    fi
    # Concatenate the array back to PATH
    PATH="${(j.:.)path_array}"
}
```

**Note on implementation**: Usually `pathmunge` implementations don't add to `PATH` if the entry already exists. I took a slightly different path - I'll remove the old instance of entry, and then add the entry as specified. The purpose is to ensure that entries are available in the expected order, since the order matters.

For example, if an entry `/foo` has commands shadowing another entry `/bar`, and I do `pathmunge before /foo` or `pathmunge after /foo` with `PATH` already containing `/foo` and `/bar` in some order, I can reasonably expect that *now* `PATH` will have the expected relative order between `/foo` and `/bar`.

Compatibility with other shells is not a concern. I am fairly competent when it comes to shell scripts. However, I have never made much use of zsh's extensive [parameter expansion](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion) features. So, I'm looking for pitfalls and performance improvements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## 1. Use *parameter expansion* for great effect

You can replace most of the `case` construct with a two `${name:#pattern}` expansions. If `pattern` matches the value of `name`, the empty string is substituted, otherwise the value of `name`. If `name` is an array, matching elements will be removed from the array. So instead of this:

```
local before

before=1
# [...]
case $1 in
    after)
        # Append to PATH
        before=
        ;&
    before)
        shift
        ;;
esac
#[...]
if [[ -n $before ]]
then
#[...]
fi
```

it would look like this:

```
local before=${1:#after}
argv=(${argv:#[^/]*})
if [[ -n $before ]]
then
#[...]
fi
```

With `before=${1:#after}` `before` will be empty if the first parameter is `"after"`, non-zero otherwise. `argv=(${argv:#[^/]*})` will remove any element from `argv` that does not start with an `/`, including `"before"` and `"after"`

One difference would be, that `before` contains the value of the first parameter instead of `1` unless said parameter was "after". But this does not matter as long as you check only if `before` is non-zero.

The second difference would be, that in addition to removing `"before"` and `"after"` from `argv`, any relative paths (or anything that does not start with an `/`) will be removed, too.

## 2. Make use of `path` instead of `PATH`

There is no need to split `PATH` into an array on your own because `zsh` already makes the value of `PATH` available as an array with the array parameter `path`. Any change to `PATH` is automatically mirrored in `path` and vice versa. So you can manipulate `path` directly without the need for the local `path_array` parameter.

Instead of

```
path_array=(${(As.:.)PATH})
path_array=(${path_array:|argv})
if [[ -n $before ]]
then
    path_array=(${(Oa)argv} $path_array)
else
    path_array=($path_array $argv)
fi
PATH="${(j.:.)path_array}"
```

You need only

```
path=(${path:|argv})
if [[ -n $before ]]
then
    path=(${(Oa)argv} $path)
else
    path=($path $argv)
fi
```

Comment: The parameter expansion method would mean that `before`/`after` *has* to be the first argument (instead of being optional, as is the case now). But in that case, I can do `[[ $before != /* ]] && shift`, I suppose - unless you have an even simpler way!

Comment: I now replaced the `shift` with another `${name:#pattern}` expansion, with the additional benefit, that it filters some arguments that are not absolute paths.